# Regex for empty route laravel 4

Tags: regex, laravel, laravel-4

I need to make a route to work on `/` and `/today` routes. Tried in this way:

```
Route::get('/{home}', function()
    {
        return View::make(...);
    })->where('home', '$^|null||today');
```

It works for `/today` but not for `/`. Also tried like this: `|today`, `today|`, `&^|today` and so on.. Nothing seems to work :) Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still define a placeholder as being optional by placing a `?` before the closing `}`.

```
Route::get('/{home?}', function()
{
    return View::make('home');
})->where('home', 'today');
```

Comment: No need to define the expression as optional, as the parameter being optional means that if no parameter is given then the route will match. If, however, a parameter is given then it must be **today** for it to match.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
Route::get('/{home}', function($home)
{
  return View::make('hello');
})->where('home','^(today|)');
```